# Master volume in final cut pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have a lot of audio tracks in a project of FCPX and I did some changes on each of them separately. Now, I want to decrease the volume of all tracks by a same amount. I was wondering if there is a simple master volume in FCPX to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a compound clip of the clips you want to adjust the volume of by selecting the clips and pressing alt-G. The volume of the compound clip as a whole can then be adjusted like a regular clip.

Comment: Although I would expect to have a master volume in FCPX. Hope they will add it in the next updates.